# How to connect to TFS using VB

Tags: vb.net, tfs

I'm writing an application that needs to connect to the Team Foundation Server, and then get the last version of a specific file from a specific project. At the begging I did this by using an external .bat, but I'd preffer running eveything inside the code.

I've been looking for examples but all I can find is written in C#. All I got so far is:

```
Dim tfs As TeamFoundationServer = New TeamFoundationServer(nameOfServer)
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you found examples in c# but you can't convert them to VB yourself, I suggest brushing up on the syntax of both languages before continuing further, otherwise you're going to get stuck again on the next obstacle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I manage to solve it:

```
Dim tfs As TeamFoundationServer = New TeamFoundationServer(serverAddress)
Dim vcs As VersionControlServer = tfs.GetService(Of VersionControlServer)()
vcs.DownloadFile(fileToGet, fileDestination)
```